# Email notification client for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, email, imap

I am looking for a program for Windows 10 that will check my account on my employer's IMAP/POP server, see if I have new mail, and ONLY add a Windows notification that a new message has arrived. That's it. No browsing, no sending. Just notifications. The server has a Web-based client that I can use to actually get the content of the message.

Nice to have but not required:

- Putting the sender and the title of the new message in the notification.
- Putting the content of the message in the notification so that I can read it right there.
- A tray icon with the number of unread messages.

Acceptable answer: Open-source C# or Visual Basic .Net code for an app that implements a simple IMAP client *and* sends the notifications. I'm a programmer and I can DIY to some extent, but I don't have enough Windows development experience (or time) to write it from scratch.